# Sorting 300K .h5 files

Tags: plotting, sorting

I have 300K .h5 files. I want to list them and plot the data with respect to a parameter. They must be sorted by name otherwise, the plot will be wrong because of time dependency. The name of the files is like  `"Fields_0.h5, Fields_10.h5, ..., Fileds_299990.h5"`. However, When I use `FileNames[]`, the order of the file is completely wrong.
I appreciate it if you could tell me how can I reach the order I mentioned.

Comment: But `FileNames` does sort its output lexicographically by the names of the files it encounters.  Perhaps what you want to do is to sort them numerically, using the numbers between the `_` and `.h5` in the file names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`SortBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html) with a custom function that extracts the number from your filename. [`FileBaseName`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileBaseName.html) is used to remove the extension, [`StringSplit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringSplit.html) to separate `"Fields"` from the number, and finally [`ToExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html) to convert string to the corresponding integer – this is neccessary so that you get a true numeric sorting, not a lexicographical one.

```
(* Change this to files = FileNames[...] *)
files = Table["Fields_" <> ToString[i] <> ".h5", {i, RandomInteger[5000, 10]}]
```

> {"Fields_221.h5", "Fields_89.h5", "Fields_282.h5", "Fields_250.h5", "Fields_12.h5"}

```
sortedFiles = SortBy[files, ToExpression[StringSplit[FileBaseName[#], "_"][[2]]] &]
```

> {"Fields_12.h5", "Fields_89.h5", "Fields_221.h5", "Fields_250.h5", "Fields_282.h5"}

Answer (score 2):

Assuming:

```
files = RandomSample @ Table["Fields_" <> ToString[i] <> ".h5", {i, 0, 300000}];
```

Here are my iterations:

#### Iteration 1

Here is a simple way to get the numbers in the given strings:

```
r1 = SortBy[files, 
    StringCases[
     "Fields_" ~~ a__ ~~ ".h5" :> 
      Internal`StringToMInteger[a]]]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* Timing: 1.04169 *)
```

#### Iteration 2

Since we know the pattern is fixed, we can use `StringTake`:

```
r2 = SortBy[files, 
    Internal`StringToMInteger@
      StringTake[#, {8, -4}] &]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* Timing: 0.635998 *)
```

#### Iteration 3

We can use the `Listable` feature to improve it even further:

```
r3 = files[[Ordering[
      Internal`StringToMInteger /@ 
       StringTake[files, {8, -4}]]]]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* Timing: 0.470797 *)
```

And of course, all of them output the same result:

```
r1 == r2 (* Out: True *)
r1 == r3 (* Out: True *)
```

Remember all of these solution use `` Internal`StringToMInteger `` to convert strings to integers which is undocumented and can be subject to change in future versions.

(Note that [@Domen](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/283179/77079) solution took `2.21771` second on the same dataset on my computer)